# How to get value/text from <button data-id="prop_type">

Tags: jquery, dropdown

Any idea how i can get a **.text or .val** from **span** or from **title** attribute? Here small html example of the code

```
<button type="button"                                                 
         class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown"    
         data-id="prop_type" title="Condo" aria-expanded="true">           
        <span class="filter-option pull-left">Condo</span>             
              </button>
```

Notice* I have a lot of dropdowns with different (data-id).
Here is **data-id="prop_type"** , how i can select this button **by data-id="prop_type"** and get the title value or *span* value? (Because the same).

*By the button class i can get..., but i have the same class for a many dropdowns.

I know this is simple, but... . :)

The last one what im try is `$('[data-id="prop_type"]').children('span').text());`
but do not work :(

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: `.text())` <- remove that last `)`

Comment: Thanks..., forget. Now works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the `<span>` value using `$('[data-id="prop_type"]').children('span').text()`. You had an extra `)`.

If you want to get the value of `title`, use this:

`$('[data-id="prop_type"]').attr('title')`

Comment: Yes. And maybe missing `$(document).ready(function(){` if it is on the head tag.
https://cr8code.co/editor.php?workid=933a35141f8c585c7278f4bf3ce6cddd

Comment: Maybe you know how to get .attr('title') if .attr('title') is change when click? Sorry if disturb you

Comment: @Ruslan can you explain? I'm not sure I understand

Comment: @BojanSrbinoski jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('[data-id="prop_type"]').on('change', 'input', function() {
    insert_title();

    function insert_title() {
      var property_type = $('[data-id="prop_type"]').attr('title');
      $('#prop_title').val(property_type);
    }
  });
});

Comment: @Ruslan what are you trying to do?

Comment: @BojanSrbinoski If i click to this button -> i have a new div -> when i choose another value -> $('[data-id="prop_type"]').attr('title') will change a value, how i can get a new value if change?